# Running Oracle stored Procedure

Tags: oracle

I have a sql file that contains a simple procedure to print "Hi" like,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE skeleton 
IS
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hi');
END;
```

When I try to execute this from sql file itself, it just gets compiled and it is not running.

I added the as,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE skeleton 
IS
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hi');
END;
/ /* this is required else it throws me compilation error*/
set serveroutput on
EXECUTE skeleton;
```

I tried calling the same skeleton from other sql file also and even from the sqldeveloper GUI, that also didnt execute this. Only the sqlplus commandline helps me. Let me know what I am missing and the solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps I took using SQL Plus

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE skeleton
  2  IS
  3  BEGIN
  4    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hi');
  5  END;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> EXECUTE skeleton;
Hi

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Can you start a new sqlplus session replicate these steps and post the content?

Comment: He said he can already run it in an interactive sqlplus session, he was just stuck running it in SQL developer and from a file.

Comment: @Colin - My bad! Amazing what happens when you read the question more than once. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only change I had to make to your sql to allow running it as an @file was to remove the comment.  This is the whole content of the the .sql file:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE skeleton
IS
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hi');
END;
/
set serveroutput on
EXECUTE skeleton;
```

You should get an output something like this:

```
C:\Temp>sqlplus username/password @skeleton.sql

SQL*Plus: Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production on Mon Oct 5 17:10:46 2009

Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Procedure created.

Hi

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Developer, you need the "execute script" button which is the second button at the top left (little green arrow in front of document) instead of the one with the big green arrow.

That threw me the first time I used it.

[image: SQL Developer]
<sub>(source: [devshed.com](https://images.devshed.com/ds/stories/Oracle_SQL_Developer/oraSqlD16.jpg))</sub>

The reason your first example gets compiled and not run, is that you are not actually asking it to run.  You are creating a procedure inside the database, which works correctly, but not calling it. In your second block you have an `EXECUTE` which is where it actually runs.

Comment: You are right about the "little green arrow in front of the document", but that is called "execute script".

Comment: Thank you!  I've not got a copy of SQL developer on this machine, I was trying to remember exactly what is was called.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting set serveroutput on before the dbms_output.

Comment: I don't think that will work.  `set serveroutput on` is not valid there.  Also I don't think `set serveroutput on` is actually required anyway, at least for SQL Developer; it will be on anyway.